# Sidebar navigation toggle with single button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have implemented the following sidebar navigation into a simple admin. I've got it working and moved to the right side. I would like to have it appear and disappear using a single button rather than a separate close and open button. I tried modifying the JS with an onToggle function that if isOpen was null, it would open the panel and then set isOpen to true and then the next time it ran, it would delete isOpen. I'm very new at JS and this failed so I thought I'd ask here. How do I get this puppy appearing and disappearing with a single button?

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Are you comfortable with `jQuery` framework or wants to do it in pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px !important;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
<body>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">☰ open</span>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>


<script>
function openNav() {
    var e = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
    if (e.style.width == '250px')
    {
        e.style.width = '0px';
    }
    else 
    {
        e.style.width = '250px';
    }
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**This is the same code with little modifications in the openNav() method**. For triggering the sideNavbar with a button, it needs to be visible before and after triggering the sideNavBar. So i have moved the view button to the top and i have modified the `top` property of `sidenav` to keep the trigger button visible even after activation

You can view this in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/ngohrvk1/

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :D

Comment: This example was the easiest for me to follow and implement.

Comment: Thanks mate! :D Glad i could help out!

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is tagged with JavaScript and you probably don't want to change the markup or add new elements. But if you could, here's a pure CSS solution that works.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.sidebar-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
#sidebar-toggle-input {
  display: none;
}
#sidebar-toggle-input+label:before {
  content: "➡️";
}
#sidebar-toggle-input:checked + label:before {
  content: "❌"
}
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
#sidebar-toggle-input:checked ~ .sidebar {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="sidebar-toggle-input" />
<label class="sidebar-toggle" for="sidebar-toggle-input"></label>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
```

Comment: I'm eager to learn alternative ways of doing things so thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you out, I have created a function and saving data-isshown attribute on the element, to get whether the element is shown or not, we can decide this on the basis of the width as well but this is more generic approach

```
function toggleNav() {
  var element = document.getElementById("mySidenav")
  var shown = element.getAttribute("data-isshown");
  if (shown == "true") {
    element.setAttribute("data-isshown", "false");
    element.style.width = "0";

  } else {
    element.setAttribute("data-isshown", "true");
    element.style.width = "250px";
  }
}
```

Whole code would look like this

```js
function toggleNav() {
  var element = document.getElementById("mySidenav")
  var shown = element.getAttribute("data-isshown");
  if (shown == "true") {
    element.setAttribute("data-isshown", "false");
    element.style.width = "0";

  } else {
    element.setAttribute("data-isshown", "true");
    element.style.width = "250px";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s
}
.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px !important;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="toggleNav()">×</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="toggleNav()">☰ open</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Up-voted. I found the first example easier to work with but thank you again. Your example has motivated me to want to learn more about retrieving element attributes once my JS skills improve.

Comment: Yahh obviously first answer is easy, but think of a case you or someone else wants its width 260 pixels, so if you change it in html you also need to change in js, you could remember this probably, but if some other guy comes he will be confused first... So always try to write generalized code... @livewithpassion

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. The first example is dependent on the specific width being 250px. In your example, the width is irrelevant because you're determining if the element is displayed or not, versus finding it's width and making a decision based on it's exact width. I'd imagine with a little more research I could pass a value into the function that would allow me to set the width of the nav bar based on the screen width.

Comment: I really don't like Bootstrap as I am building a desktop-first admin panel that has an iOS mobile application for mobile. Using @Media to detect screen resolution, I already have my UI re-sizing at various breakpoints or introducing new elements as I'm using flexbox for my layout. It's pretty easy to turn one element off using width and another on at the breakpoints. I have much to learn here. Thank you kindly for you advice.